# WebSQL type casting columns

Tags: sql, types, casting, web-sql

I have two tables with a common column which I am trying to join. How ever due to circumstances which I have no control over, one of the columns stores data as a string, the other as an integer. I need to convert the string column to an integer, or vice versa. How would I do this? In PgSQL it would be as easy as column::text etc but I cannot get something working on WebSQL. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply cast the INT column to VARCHAR?

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT);
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID VARCHAR(2));

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('3');

SELECT  *
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN T2
            ON T2.ID = CAST(T.ID AS VARCHAR(2));
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e215e/1)**

You could also use `CAST(VarcharColumn AS INT)`, but you are more likely to encounter conversion errors casting from string to int, than from int to string.